# Outline rendering Bug in iOS Safari

Tags: html, css, ios, safari, outline

Safari on iOS 14 and probably below has a bug with the outline of the summary tag.

If I open the details tag it will break the line:
[image: iOS outline bug]

And the same thing in Edge Chromium:
[image]

I tried setting the width and height of the "icon" in order to reduce the box to the minimum but unfortunately that does not work.

Here is a link to the website: https://live.spardasurfsafe-bw.de/

Here is a code snipped with the used css:

```css
summary {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    position: relative;
}

 summary::marker,
 summary::-webkit-details-marker {
    color: transparent;
 }

 summary::after {
    content:  "+";
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 2em;
    top: -.3em;
    margin-left: 10px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
 }

 details[open] summary::after {
  transform: translate(5px,0) rotate(45deg);
 }
```

```html
<details>
    <summary>foo</summary>
    <ul>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>baz</li>
    </ul>
</details>
<details>
    <summary>foo</summary>
    <ul>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>baz</li>
    </ul>
</details>
<details>
    <summary>foo</summary>
    <ul>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>baz</li>
    </ul>
</details>
```

Comment: Could you update your snippet so it shows the outline and hence the problem?

Comment: Well I can't update the snippet because it shows the problem already on iOS Safari. In other browsers it looks totally fine. I added a link to the website. Maybe that helps

Comment: Ah, I must be interpreting things wrongly because on my browser (Edge) there is no outline shown in the snippet. What should I be looking at?

Comment: I added a Screenshot in Edge. It's visible if you tab into the element that the "icon" is too large and therefore causes a bug in Safari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Safari renders pseudo elements not inline as the other browsers. It can almost reproduced in Chromium browsers with `display: inline-block;` on the pseudo-element and removing `position: absolute`:

```css
summary {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    position: relative;
}

 summary::marker,
 summary::-webkit-details-marker {
    color: transparent;
 }

 summary::after {
    content:  "+";
    font-size: 2em;
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 0;
 }

 details[open] summary::after {
  transform: translate(5px,0) rotate(45deg);
 }
```

```html
<details>
    <summary>foo</summary>
    <ul>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>baz</li>
    </ul>
</details>
<details>
    <summary>foo</summary>
    <ul>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>baz</li>
    </ul>
</details>
<details>
    <summary>foo</summary>
    <ul>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>baz</li>
    </ul>
</details>
```

In order to fix this issue all I had to do was to restrict the overflow for the "parent" element (summary `overflow: hidden;`):

```css
summary {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

 summary::marker,
 summary::-webkit-details-marker {
    color: transparent;
 }

 summary::after {
    content:  "+";
    font-size: 2em;
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 0;
 }

 details[open] summary::after {
  transform: translate(5px,0) rotate(45deg);
 }
```

```html
<details>
    <summary>foo</summary>
    <ul>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>baz</li>
    </ul>
</details>
<details>
    <summary>foo</summary>
    <ul>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>baz</li>
    </ul>
</details>
<details>
    <summary>foo</summary>
    <ul>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>baz</li>
    </ul>
</details>
```